# In IE, how do I remove a filter?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a class

`.tab{filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5ffff', endColorstr='#e8f2f8');}`

and when one of the tabs is selected I want to remove the filter:

```
.tab.selectedtab{/*what do I put here to remove the filter?*/}
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The answer is to set the enabled property of the filter like so:

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);`

Comment: accepted answer also works for another MS property in newest versions of IE "-ms-filter" : -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false)";

Answer (score 22):

I've only tried this in IE8, but it seems to do the trick:

`filter: none;`

Comment: I used this version before and then tried the accepted answer. This one didn't work for me in IE8.

Comment: This line fails on W3C CSS validator

Answer (score 8):

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false)";
filter: none;
```