# css: filters how to disable them for a certain class?

Tags: css, filter

On IE I'm having a bit of trouble with my CSS:

```
body.transparent {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, -1px 0 #000;
   filter: Glow(color=#000000, strength=1);
}
body.transparent a {
   text-shadow: none;
   filter: -;
}
```

The `Glow` filter needs to be excluded on `body.transparent a`, like the `text-shadow` is. But I just can't disable the filter for the links. How do I do this??

Comment: I think it is `filter: none`, not `-`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you cant override the filter in child elements. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768161/how-do-i-reset-or-override-ie-css-filters), there the solution was to give the child a `absolute` or `relative` position.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly override the filter by negating it.

```
.parent-element{
    filter: hue-rotate(210deg);
}
.unfilter-child{
    filter: hue-rotate(-210deg); 
}
```

Comment: Although after trying this particular solution it is apparent that rotating the hue twice creates an inaccurate final color .. so in the case of color hue .. perhaps not

Answer (score 0):

Try `filter:image` that is the default value

**EDIT**

Then try this `filter: Glow(Color=#ffffff, Strength=1)`

and this `filter: Glow(Color=#ffffff, Strength=0)`

Comment: I've just played around a bit, and it looks like filters aren't really inherited in the way that, say, `font-weight` is. Giving the `<a>` its own filter won't replace the parent element's filter, it'll just superimpose one filter on the other.

Comment: nothing.. after i set it to glow in the "main class" it overrides every other filter i set up in the subclass..

Comment: I've found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036963/in-ie-how-do-i-remove-a-filter