# How to remove filter inheritance from child IE CSS

Tags: internet-explorer

How to remove 'filter' attribute to inherit for the child element for IE8?
So I have parent with:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=135, Color='#f69041');
```

This automatically inherits to the child element that we don't want.

In the child element I tried it:

```
 position:relative;
```

Or

```
 filter:none;
```

and other kind of things with no results, at all times, the child inherits parents 'filter' styling. How can I prevent it from inheriting for IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037037/615511) by Kyle. In your case override the filter with:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(enabled = false);
```