# Background png doesn't display in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, background-image

The background image used for the navigation shows up fine in Firefox and Chrome.  But Internet Explorer 7 doesn't show it at all. The website in question is [www.vickieats.com](http://www.vickieats.com/)

The CSS:

```
.navbar-inner{
   background:url(images/bg-nav.png) repeat-x left #d0a86a;
   border-radius:12px;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a{
   color:#FFF;
   font-size:1.25em;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding:28px 35px;
   text-shadow:0 1px #000;
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover{
   color:#6E5632;
}
```

I'm sure it's something silly, so please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove filter from .navbar-inner and then try.

Comment: If you need it set, and then want to remove it (good for hover effects and such), check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036963/in-ie-how-do-i-remove-a-filter

Answer (score 0):

i've noticed that you have given one position in your css  try to give both position

```
.navbar-inner{
   background:url(images/bg-nav.png) repeat-x left top #d0a86a;
   border-radius:12px;
}
```

and also you can try this css hope this will work and let me know if you have any problem

```
 .navbar-inner{
       background-image:url(images/bg-nav.png);
       background-color:#d0a86a;
       background-repeat:repeat-x;
       background-position:top left;
       border-radius:12px;
    }
```